# Fiware Cygnus Error

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Looking for why my information was not persisting in Cosmos I have found this error in the log of cygnus repeated hundreds of times:

```
03 Sep 2015 02:20:18,491 ERROR [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process:103)  - Channel error (The Flume transaction could not be started. Details=begin() called when transaction is OPEN!)

03 Sep 2015 02:20:18,491 ERROR [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run:160)  - Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.

org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:104)
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
    at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:101)
    ... 3 more
```

Is it a configuration error or a runtime error?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** This is a configuration file content of an agent:

```
# Copyright 2014 Telefónica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
# 
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
# 
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
# 
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

#=============================================
# To be put in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/agent.conf
#
# General configuration template explaining how to setup a sink of each of the available types (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL).

#=============================================
# The next tree fields set the sources, sinks and channels used by Cygnus. You could use different names than the
# ones suggested below, but in that case make sure you keep coherence in properties names along the configuration file.
# Regarding sinks, you can use multiple types at the same time; the only requirement is to provide a channel for each
# one of them (this example shows how to configure 3 sink types at the same time). Even, you can define more than one
# sink of the same type and sharing the channel in order to improve the performance (this is like having
# multi-threading).
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = hdfs-sink
cygnusagent.channels = hdfs-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = my_service
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = my_path
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 0
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
#cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
#cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionHDFSSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink
# Comma-separated list of FQDN/IP address regarding the HDFS Namenode endpoints
# If you are using Kerberos authentication, then the usage of FQDNs instead of IP addresses is mandatory
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_host = cosmos.lab.fiware.org
# port of the HDFS service listening for persistence operations; 14000 for httpfs, 50070 for webhdfs
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_port = 14000
# username allowed to write in HDFS
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username = my_username
# OAuth2 token
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token = my_token
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.attr_persistence = column
# Hive FQDN/IP address of the Hive server
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_host = cosmos.lab.fiware.org
# Hive port for Hive external table provisioning
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_port = 10000
# Kerberos-based authentication enabling
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth = false
# Kerberos username
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_user = krb5_username
# Kerberos password
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_password = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
# Kerberos login file
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_login_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/krb5_login.conf
# Kerberos configuration file
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/krb5.conf

#=============================================
# hdfs-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.capacity = 10000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

Comment: Which version of Cygnus are you running? Which is your configuration? This is an error about an inconsistent status of the internal queue used by Apache Flume (the technology Cygnus relies on), it could appear in very old versions of Cygnus.

Comment: We are using the version 0.8.2 of Cygnus and we have 4 cygnus instances running that are listening on different ports but have the same sink.

Comment: Do you mean 4 different Cygnus processes? Or 4 different HTTPSources within the same Cygnus process, all of them contributing to a single channel which is consumed by a single sink? Anyway, can you edit the question and paste the particular configuration you are using, please?

Comment: We have 4 different HTTP sources within the same Cygnus, sorry. I have edited the question for include a configuration file of an agent (called agent_a.conf). The other agents are listening on ports 5051, 5052 and 5053. Anyway this error has not appeared anymore after a reboot of the system.

Comment: Do you have 4 files like the one above, one per each port? In that case, you are running 4 different agents/processes of Cygnus (what's perfectly valid, just for having clear the scenario :)). In that case, even if the channel names are the same, they are 4 different instances of the channel, one per agent. The same occur with sinks, they will be 4 different sinks despite they are named the same, and they will be working in parallel (what is good).

Comment: Yes, that is our configuration.